# Can a radio transmitter somehow detect the number of receivers in its area?

Tags: rf, signal, radio, transmitter, receiver

During conversation, a colleague proposed that over-the-air television and radio broadcasters can determine the number of viewers or listeners based on the "load" on their signal. This seems to me like total bupkis, but he's piqued my curiosity and I've not been able to find a discernible answer when searching the web to prove him right or wrong.

Is such a thing even possible? Do the number of receivers within the broadcast range of a transmitter put any "load" on that signal? I always thought that the amount of power required for a transmitter simply determined the distance at which the signal could still be reliably received. AFAIK receiving a radio signal does not require any actual power at the listener's end, except to filter and amplify that signal into something useful, and that power is provided locally.

If this were true, it seemed plausible to me that one could place several signal monitors at a fixed radius from the transmitter and measure the signal strength at each. Monitors with weaker signal must have more receivers between that monitor and the transmitter, which could be used to extrapolate the number of receivers within that arc of the radius at, say, -3 dBm per receiver.

What I do know is that *obstructions* between the transmitter and receiver degrade the strength of the signal, so in that situation, one would have to account for buildings, trees, mountains, birds, precipitation, clouds, airplanes, helicopters, low-flying kayaks, large snowmen, and Santa Claus.

Comment: May be since in the near field, and especially in the reactive near field (λ/2π distance from antenna), there is  no transmission as an electromagnetic wave, and may apply to either inductively or capacitively coupled. In this area E and H becomes really very complex.

Comment: For what it's worth, viewer statistics for radio and television are typically determined through listener studies, e.g. by Arbitron in the US.

Comment: It is just as possible as the number of plants or eyeballs having an influence on the sun's radiation output. All forms of electromagnetic energy become heat 100%. So, any sort of receiver, even a charcoal brick, is an equivalent "load" as the signal propagates away... To Infinity, And Beyond!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Actually, yes, a receiver can affect the transmitter. Passive RFID is based on this principle.

However, RFID only works at very close distances, where the receiver is absorbing something on the order of 10<sup>-4</sup> to 10<sup>-5</sup> of the transmitter's signal. In other words, the transmitter is sending out hundreds of milliwatts, while the receiver is absorbing a few microwatts. Such changes are just barely detectable at the transmitter with careful techniques.

However, for general broadcast radio, the transmitter is sending out tens to hundreds of kilowatts, while the receiver is absorbing tens to hundreds of femtowatts, which is a fraction on the order of 10<sup>-18</sup>. This is completely undetectable at the transmitter. Furthermore, receivers absorb signal regardless of whether they're turned on or not, so even if it were detectable, it would tell you nothing about how many people were actually listening.

Comment: Even there, small RFID tags work by actually taking the wireless power from the transmitter (RFID Reader) and transmitting back.  longer distance tags (smart tolls, aircraft ID'd) use powered tags.  If it weren't for the tag's transmission of data, the transmitter would know nothing.

Comment: @RDrast: With passive RFID, the transmitter sends a continuous carrier, and the "transmitting back" by the tag is done on the same frequency. This is sensed on the transmitter by measuring small variations in the carrier amplitude at the antenna terminals. In effect, the tag is varying how much energy it is absorbing from the transmitter in a recognizable pattern. Active RFID uses completely different techniques.

Comment: If it is actually RFID, then the tag is actually transmitting back information after being powered up by the passive field.  I know of no systems that do not include a a digital ID signature that is read by the reader, encoding information onto the returned data.

Comment: @RDrast: Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: Further-furthermore: when talking about receivers from the point of view of the RF signal, large bodies of water, living meat (people, cats, cattle..) walls of a certain color or material and mountains made of certain types of rocks also count as receivers (they also absorb the signal). So any attempt to count receivers based on the load at the transmitter is merely characterizing the environment the transmitter is in.

Comment: RFID Tags based on NFC work through induction and can transmit data by modulating the load. That’s why their antennas are coils and they only work over some centimeters.

Comment: @DaveTweed No, it isn't what you said.  The Transmitter doesn't detect anything to do with changes in its transmitted power at all. It receives a digital signature from the tag, which is powered up by the transmitted field.  The tag gets powered by the field, and spits back a transmission of its own.  The reader can't detect any changes in its actual transmitted field.  If that were the case, readers couldn't identify 100's of items in a box individually.  The RFID Tags are smart, transmitters, and take power from the field to activate.

Comment: @RDrast: There are different types of RFID tags for different applications. The ones that Dave Tweed is talking about do not send back a separate transmission, and they do indeed just put intermittently more "load" on the transmitter (in a specific pattern that encodes the tag's id, which the transmitter is able to detect and decode). Often this does indeed mean the readers can only identify one tag at a time (though some types do have collision avoidance protocols); yes, this is useless for identifying 100s of items in a box, but is fine for (say) letting a person (/animal!) into a building.

Comment: Those are not RFID tags.  They are radio theft prevention tags, which do operate be being a resonant tuned circuit that measures as a detectable dip to the transmitter.  Still, that system can only count a single tag as being present.  If there are 20, it doesn't know that, and there is no identification of the actual tag.

Comment: @RDrast: No, the tags we are talking about genuinely are RFID tags (theft prevention tags are something else). In the tags in question (eg tags conforming to ISO11784/11785) there *is* a digital identification that the receiver can detect (and distinguish from other tags).

Comment: And again, according to the same standard, for half duplex tags, the  "tag must store sufficient energy when the receiver's activating field is turned on to allow it to transmit when the activating field is switched off."  The actual transmitter cannot tell if there is a listener by monitoring its output power, which was the original question.

Comment: @RDrast: We're talking about the FDX ones here. The receiver can (and does) tell if there is a listener by monitoring its own transmission. If you want to know more about it I suggest looking into how simple 125kHz RFID tag readers work.

Comment: Point me to a document then.  125KHZ FDX tags still TRANSMIT their own data to the reader.  The reader does not interpret a magical shift in the RF field to detect the tag.  For ANY RFID, the tag MUST transmit, or there is no ID.

Comment: @RDrast: It does communicate, but it doesn't "transmit" in any conventional sense of the word - it communicates, as Dave Tweed already said, by modulating the the energy in the transmitting antenna by absorbing more or less of the transmitted energy - very roughly, it might put its coil into "high absorbence" mode to send back a 1, "low absorbence" to send back a 0. If you want more details, I suggest you do your own searches or ask a question here :)

Comment: I'm done here.  Point me to something that operates that way, and I'll be a believer, but I'm done in this.

Comment: @RDrast: If you're genuinely interested, here are some examples of a very simple [tag](http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/) and [reader](http://scanlime.org/2008/08/simplest-rfid-reader/) with some details on how they work.

Comment: This may be knitpicky, but: No, the transmitter cannot detect this, only an additional receiver (the RFID reader consists of transmitter **and receiver**). Furthermore, it still **cannot** detect if there is a receiver (tag) or not. I can only distinguish if the tag reflects the signal or not. If the receiver would be perfectly matched and absorb all received signals (without reflecting), it can still receive all data. But the receiver of the RFID reader **cannot** distinguish this from "no tag there" (assuming free space).

Comment: @divB Here the word "transmitter" is used to mean the component of the system which radiates RF energy.

Answer (score 25):

It's technically possible to detect radio receivers if they are [Superheterodyne receivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver) that use RF mixing to downmix the received signal to a well known intermediate frequency. You can scan for this frequency using a directional antenna and count the receivers around you.

Though this doesn't sound like what you're inferring since the transmitter can't detect the receiver based on signal "load" or other factors, it requires a special detector that's separate from the transmitter.

This is how [radar detector detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_detector_detector) work. Also, some billboards use this technology to determine what radio station drivers are listening to so they can tailor the ads to the drivers' preferences:

- [Billboards That Know You](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/12/14/magazine/14BILLBOARDS.html)
- [High-tech billboards tune in to drivers' tastes](http://www.sfgate.com/bayarea/article/High-tech-billboards-tune-in-to-drivers-tastes-2744204.php)

Comment: So if the radio company owned several such billboards in the area, connected to them somehow (cell radio perhaps)... I think they would be able to have a reasonable guess per the OP's question

Comment: It somewhat reminds this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%28listening_device%29

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1

Comment: While this would work for relatively short distances, it seems highly unlikely this would be any help in the case given by the OP.

Comment: This works only if the mixer in the receiver is a very bad mixer that reflects some of the mixing product back to the antenna or leaks it somewhere else in such a large amount that it can detected from a distance AND if the exact IF is known. In addition this method could be easily undermined by using an unusual IF. Also there are dozens of other  possible sources that would leak EM radiation of the same  particular frequency (e.g. harmonics of µC-clocks). So practically there is NO WAY to use this to find radio receivers tuned to a particular station.

Comment: Reminds me of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_detector_van

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like complete and utter cr*p for all practical purposes. The actual energy extracted by a receiver is microscopic.

Though there **is** a story of a farmer who built a big tuned loop in order to extract free power from a nearby radio transmitter. Sufficient to distort the field pattern and be detected.

Comment: I heard that near radio towers usage of neon lights is prohibited because it lights up from the strong signal. But thats just heard.

Comment: @akaltar If you hold a flourescent tube light under those big transmission lines with one end closer to the lines, it will light up.  I'm pretty sure that our two situations are based off the same principle.

Comment: Even if, this microscopic "energy extracted" can still not be distinguished from being radiated into outer space forever (assuming it is not reflected somewhere and find its way back to the transmitting station).

Answer (score 11):

No.
There is no way for an AM or FM transmitter to determine how many people are listening.  They provide exactly the same power output at carrier whether there are a million receivers within 1 mile or zero.

Digital transmissions that require a subscription can on the other hand possibly know how many receivers there are, if there is a two way verification link.  Or like WiFi, each 'receiver' is actually interacting with the transmitter, but in neither case does it affect the output power of the transmitter, or is it able to be sensed by monitoring the output power.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the the field in question is the electromagnetic field, and all interactions are in the 'far field', then the question is 100% no, no you cannot sense increased load.

RF is just the production of light, albeit a frequency much lower than visible (WiFi runs at 2.4 GHz. Red light is ~400 THz).

Does a star experience more 'drain' because its light is being absorbed by my eye? Or a piece of silicon? Or a spherical cow?

Does a light bulb experience more 'drain' because its light is being absorbed by my office walls?

The is answer is absolutely no, once the antenna has produced photons, the energy is gone and all drain on that device to produce that photon has already occurred.

...

The answer is different if you consider near field - where inductive reactance dominates. This is how purely-passive, non-transmitting RFID tags mentioned in the comments work - they have an inductive circuit that is tuned to the frequency of the inductor that makes up the antenna, like a big open-air transformer. Here the antenna/transformer/inductor does actually sense increased load, because it is being coupled to the RFID's inductor.

Near field, however, only operates within about 1 wavelength from the transmitter. This is why near-field purely-passive non-transmitting RFID tags must use low frequencies, so that they can have reasonable operating distances.

A good reference is the following paper by two IEEE RF scientists:
http://www.ee.washington.edu/faculty/nikitin_pavel/papers/RFID_2007.pdf

To quote:

> Low frequency (LF, 125-134 KHz) and high frequency
> (HF, 13.56 MHz) RFID systems are short range systems
> based on inductive coupling between the reader and the tag
> antennas through a magnetic field. Ultra-high frequency
> (UHF, 860-960 MHz) and microwave (2.4 GHz and 5.8
> GHz) RFID systems are long-range systems which use
> electromagnetic waves propagating between reader and tag
> antennas

Some wavelength calculations for those above frequencies, for the curious:

- 125 KHz == 2398.34 meters
- 13.56 MHz == 22.11 meters
- 2.4 GHz == 0.125 meters

Answer (score 6):

This is explained [here in detail](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node94.html):

> So, in the optimum case half of the power absorbed by the antenna is immediately re-radiated. Clearly, an antenna which is receiving electromagnetic radiation is also emitting it. This is how the BBC catch people who do not pay their television license fee in England. They have vans which can detect the radiation emitted by a TV aerial whilst it is in use (they can even tell which channel you are watching!).

Comment: FTR, this is quite different from, as in the question, the transmission tower detecting it.  Also purely for the record, in the vast majority of cases the authorities in the UK simply track purchase of TV sets at electronics stores, and align those records.  (Which is quite chilling!)

Comment: That sounds bogus as the re-radiated energy would be the same frequency and signal modulation as the source. I think the detector vans used a directional antenna to pick up the TV's internal oscillator frequencies.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to detect the number of receivers from transmitting point. Once the EM wave leaves the near field of the antenna the wave becomes transversal electromagnetic wave and it has no influence on transmitter. 
However there is an interaction between sorrounding antennas at close distance (near field - half wavelength), but this is barely detectable.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it could be estimated. A known power level source will transmit to a certain distance before losing signal strength to half power (-3db). Every antenna and receiver between the source and that -3db distance will tap some of the power from the signal. If you have a receiver sensitive enough at the -3db distance, the number of interfering listeners in between could be estimated. Now, do that process in a circular pattern around the source and you could estimate the number of signal interceptors between the source and the known power level perimeter.
A similar process can be used in cable transmission by determining the amount of signal power needed to maintain that -3db level at the end of the transmission line. (ie, each receiver requires 5 milliwatts to show the signal to its receiver, the end of the line will see a minus 5 milliwatts for each customer watching that channel between the source and the line end. If the end of the line experiences a half watt signal strength loss (500 milliwatts) it means 100 people are tuned to that channel.

That is doable physics. Whether the radio stations or cable providers do it is not known.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(telecommunications)

Comment: 1. Receiving antennas in the path will extract the same power from the signal whether they are being listened to  or not. 2. So would (maybe not quite so efficiently) every building, tree, vehicle, cow, telephone pole, etc.,

Comment: Those trees and cows need to pay their TV fee!

Comment: Is there a reason why you pick -3dB? -3dB will be usually be in the near field, no? In the radiative far field, you would have a much higher attenuation

Answer (score 3):

Interessting question...

in an shielded labarotory, with a well defined receiver - maybe you can.
In a real world scenario with all kinds of receivers from different manufaturers, aged, defect, and hundreds of enviromental distubance sources... Its a definitive No I would say.

I knew eg. sending towers powered nearby light chains in gardens without being pluged to a power supply (which was detected as it weakend the transmitters signal a lot). Other people reported a shovel in some special place and position to play radio. Everything matching some multiples of the signals wavelength drews power from the HF signal without being a valid receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Superhet receivers are  still the norm at present .They have a local oscillater and use standard intermediate frequencies .So it would give predicted lo radiation .For example a 1593 KHz AM station would make the receiver tune its lo to 2048KHz if it was picking up the station .Specailised narrowband           equipment could pick up this carrier spouting out from the receivers antenna .If the receivers are not very good it is  in theory  possible to pick up this lo radiation .Very haed to do .Now if you quickly key the transmitter off and on so it is not noticed you could pick up a chirp in the lo due to pulling if the receiver is really cheap.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be well answered by now but just to be sure - the load could be increased by a receiver in the near field, but once the signal is ‘emitted’ there’s no way to know what has happened to it.  The RF energy will be absorbed one way or another and it’s impossible to tell whether a signal has been received and interpreted or just absorbed.